# React JS Rest API Security With GoLang Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, authentication, go

I have built a ReactJS Frontend with GoLang Backend. All the data is being requested/sent by ReactJS from/to Golang Backend using Rest APIs.

I am quite confused on what will the best way to secure my API requests so that one does not pro-grammatically hit my backend server and make undesired changes. Any advice will be really appreciated.

I have been exploring JWT tokens and CSRF tokens but am not going anywhere with how to exactly implement it in my application due to my lack of expertise in the API security domain.

Some further details about my application are:

1. The frontend and backend server are separate.
2. The frontend server is using Nginx to serve the static files.
3. A new token should be generated everytime the page is opened and it should be valid for no more than 8 minutes.

Please suggest to me what would be the best way to secure my rest APIs given the structure of my application.

P.S.: There is no login or any other mechanism for this page which would establish the authenticity of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JWT for API security as your token expiry time is short enough.

- https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go --> Use this package to generate token in backend and set expiry time and claims as per your need. Your claims can have granular control(Auth layer) too based on roles.
- Send this token to your front end from login or any endpoint which is the gateway to your API.
- Store the token in local storage/https cookie as per your wish at your front end.
- With every API call which needed to be secured send this token in header, validate this token at back-end using the library mentioned above.
- Challenge will be to invalidate these tokens on forgot or reset  password/logout. You can use blacklist token technique by keeping them in redis/db and flushing them regularly with cron.

Comment: That makes sense Kunal. But here's something that I am sceptical about:

There is no login, so a person does not have to enter any unique credential that can establish there authenticity. In such case, if a token is simply generated by calling the api, cant the same api be used by a malicious user to generated multiple tokens and then call unlimited number of other apis with those generated tokens?

Comment: Usually, tokens are generated on top of some basic Authentication layer(username, password). There must be some layer that segregates Authentic and malicious users then only token based authentication can be implemented.

Comment: Your case is a bit open ended, you can have Tokens wtih shorter expiry time and do rate limiting on API. That will serve your purpose.

Comment: Basically, the use case is for a web checkout, where a user necessarily need not sign in to proceed with the transaction. But still because the APIs are being used for very sensitive purposes, token or keys are a must to ensure the authenticity of the requests. Cors implementation are a way but they can be easily spoofed by anyone. This is why am struggling to find the best way to secure these apis.

API rate limiter has already been enforced on the server side. But I want to implement initial layer of security with some for of api key protection as well.